# Having trouble with Authentication flow using react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

I am new to react native and I am having trouble setting up the persistence login. I feel like I did authentication correctly I could be wrong and I want to redirect authenticated users to the main screen but I keep getting this error from my navigation container in my app.js file.

The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Main","params":{"usersRef":"aidan.j.puthussery@gmail.com","uid":"gGpXwbdMm3hSjrTItFMYcpKrbHq2"}} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'Main'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production.

I have tried to use this code:

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      {!user ? (
        <Stack.Group>
          <Stack.Screen name = "Landing" component={LandingScreen}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
        </Stack.Group>
      ) : (
        <Stack.Group>
          <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen} />
        </Stack.Group>
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

however this is were the error appears and I have also looked into Async storage with setting the user data to an item but I am not sure how to set that up just yet I am still learning it and there is a ton of information online do not know where to start. Any help will be very helpful. Thank you!

Here is my App.js:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import RegisterScreen from './components/Authentication/Register';
import LandingScreen from './components/Authentication/Landing';
import LoginScreen from './components/Authentication/Login';
import MainScreen from './components/Main';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore, collection, doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import firebaseApp from './components/firebase/config';
import { decode, encode } from 'base-64';

if (!global.btoa) {
  global.btoa = encode;
}
if (!global.atob) {
  global.atob = decode;
}

export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  useEffect(() => {
    const firebase = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
    const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
    const usersRef = collection(firebase, 'users');

    console.log('##usersRef', usersRef);

    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user);
        getDoc(doc(usersRef, user.uid))
          .then((document) => {
            const userData = document.data();
            setLoading(false);
            setUser(userData);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            setLoading(false);
          });
      } else {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      {!user ? (
        <Stack.Group>
          <Stack.Screen name = "Landing" component={LandingScreen}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
        </Stack.Group>
      ) : (
        <Stack.Group>
          <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen} />
        </Stack.Group>
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```